# How can I earn "Car Collector" achievement in Rocket League?

Tags: achievements, rocket-league

"Car Collector" achievement says that you need to unlock 5 cars to get it. If I recall correctly I started with 3 initial cars and I've already unlocked more than 5, here is my garage with 13 cars:

[image: 133-cars-in-my-garage]

I've tried to follow [this guide](https://www.trueachievements.com/a212804/car-collector-achievement) - I finished the Season Championship and then got 1 win for all of my cars in Exhibition mode, but still cannot unlock this achievement or get more cars. Looks like something was changed in recent F2P update.

How can I unlock this achievement now?

I play on PS4.

Answer (score 1):

To unlock the "Car Collector" achievement, in Rocket League, you simply have to unlock 5 cars.

Checking back on some achievement guides I followed when I unlocked it, I confirmed that most of the cars are unlocked just by completing matches.

---

When it comes to the achievement still not unlocking; there are a lot of reports of this achievement being bugged - especially as of the game becoming free-to-play.

- I found one instance where the user had unlocked all cars available to the free-to-play model of the game. They than purchased a single DLC car, and had the achievement immediately unlock.
- I found a few instances where users reported success by uploading their save profiles to their cloud storage, deleting their local save files, deleting and reinstalling the game and re-downloading their save profiles from their cloud storage. *This appears to be the most reliable solution, as I have found multiple users reporting that this worked for them across multiple platforms*.
- [I found another user reporting this as a bug on PSN Profiles](https://forum.psnprofiles.com/topic/95740-car-collector-bug/). A user by the name of *roenroe* reports having success by linking their account with a Steam version of the game:

> 1. Complete all other main trophies
> 2. Create on pc steam account
> 3. [www.rocketleague.com/activate](http://www.rocketleague.com/activate)
> 4. Change your main account to steam account
> 5. Download your save data to ps plus or USB
> 6. Delete yourt save data
> 7. Start the game without data (no reinstall needed)
> 8. Enjoy your platinum trophy

- I found a few instances where users report completely wiping their save progress; both from their local console and cloud storage. They then started a fresh save, and manually unlocked the achievement without further issue. Naturally, this is the nuclear option; but if your eager to unlock that platinum trophy, it might be one you consider.